# Restart ID of an item in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Good morning friends. I'm using Google translator, so I apologize for mistakes in the text.

I'm developing a system based on **MEAN**.

I'm using a plugin called **mongoose-auto-increment** to generate the ID numbers of each item in my database. So far so good, but the problem is that every ***January 1st at 00:00 hours*** that ID must be restarted again, ie, the first item stored in the database the new year must have the ID Number 1 and go adding the following.

*This obviously without overwriting the article with the ID number 1 of the previous years.*

I've been researching a lot but can not find any solution to my situation, I'm probably not using the right keywords. I appreciate any help you can give me.

Best regards :-)

Answer (score 0):

ID's are unique.  If you want to use the same incrementing range twice, you'll need to make it unique somehow.  Perhaps make the id custom and prepend the year.  2014_1, 2014_2 etc will play nice with 2015_1, 2015_2 etc

Your alternative is just to index a secondary field (perhaps named "alternateID" or whatever) and leave the _id to generate by itself  - then query from the alternateID field instead.

Comment: Hi James. Thanks for your answer.

That's what I'm doing, I have a secondary field for custom ID called "code".

I wonder how to add a prefix, for example the current year to that custom ID.

The _id field not modified. Thanks and sorry for not having explained well.